# Find $\pmb{\widehat{\beta}_1}$ and $\pmb{\widehat{\beta}_2}$, two different solutions to the normal equations $\,\mathbf{X'X\pmb{\beta}= X'Y}$.

Tags: statistical-inference

[image]

This is my attempt at a solution.
Please help complete the solution, and I will be grateful to everyone who helps me
my try.

Comment: What is $\mathbf{X’}$ ? And what is $\pmb{\epsilon}$ ?

Comment: @Angelo almost surely the matrix transpose

Comment: What are $\,\mathcal C(\mathbf X)\,$ and $\,\mathcal N(\mathbf X’)$ ?

Comment: One solution is obtained by estimating the Moore_Penrose inverse $X^+$ of $X$: $beta_+=X^+y$. More solutions are obtained by adding to $\beta_+$ solutions to the homogeneous equation $Xu=0$.